# Updating dropdown value without rebuild all widget tree Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my first question at StackOverflow, I'm a flutter and dart newbie so I hope to get some help from here.

I'm coding an app that use a TableCalendar to make appointments, I load data in some dates in the calendar using the "events" property, so when I pick any date, if that date has data I load its data in a Dropdown button, I'm using a Stream broadcast() to listen to every time I pick a date so dropdown items change according to the date.

Up to this point I have no problem, the problem is when my dropdown items are ready and I try to pick another value inside the dropdown menu, since the value needs to be updated using OnChanged property, I need to call the setState, but when I do that all the widget tree is rebuilt, and if I don't use the setState obviously the value doesn't change.

I need to update only the dropdown menu item without redrawing all the widget trees keeping the actual state of all the other widgets except the dropdown value and I've been looking from here and there for any solution but I don't find it.

The TableCalendar and the DropdownButton are inside a Listview, the data source is a JSON file, I'm using a Future Builder to build the ListView and a StreamBuilder to build the DropdownButton.

This is the dropdown code:

```
 StreamBuilder(
            stream: streamHora.stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return DropdownButton<String>(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  style: _textStyle(Colors.black, 15.0),
                  items: [],
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                  value: "",
                );
              }
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                style: _textStyle(Colors.black, 15.0),
                items: snapshot.data,
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dropdownHoraValue = value;
                  });
                },
                value: _dropdownHoraValue,
              );
            },
          ),
```

Any idea or suggestion will be very appreciated.